# Issue with geom_smooth in a time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am having an issue with ggplot. My geom_smooth() curve is the same for three data sets. I have been playing with the data for hours now and I am still stumped.

Any ideas?

code:

```
COVID <- StatCovid <- read_excel("StatCovid.xlsx", sheet = "Organized")

United_States <- COVID %>% group_by(United_States) %>% select(dateRep, United_States)
France <- COVID %>% group_by(France) %>% select(dateRep, France)
India <- COVID %>% group_by(India)%>% select(dateRep, India)

ggplot(data = COVID, mapping = aes(x= ymd(dateRep), y= COVID$United_States)) + 
geom_point(color = "red") + 
geom_point(data = COVID, aes(x= ymd(dateRep), y= COVID$France), color= "blue") +
geom_point(data = COVID, aes(x= ymd(dateRep), y= COVID$India), color = "green") +
geom_smooth(data = United_States, aes(color = "United_States"),se = F)+
geom_smooth(data = France, aes(color = "France"),se = F)+
geom_smooth(data = India, aes(color = "India"),se = F)+
scale_color_manual(name = "Country", values = c(United_States = "red", France = "blue", India ="green"))+
theme_classic() + xlab(NULL) +ylab("Number of New Cases Found")+ labs(title = "Spread of COVID-19 as a result of Holiday Travel")
```

The end goal of my chart is to have a shaded region with a given width around the same time as holidays to see if covid spread more during the holidays.

This is just showing how the smooth geom is the same.
[image]

reference with 1
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: You haven't definied any aesthethics mappings for your geom_smooths, so they use the aes from your ggplot call. Try adding e.g. aes(x= ymd(dateRep), y= COVID$France)

Comment: You will probably find ggplot easier if you reshape the data with `pivot_longer ` first